# A period after "however"

Tags: punctuation

Is it right to put a period after *however*?
Because while reading a sentence I saw:

> Conceptualizing a game is only the beginning of a video game
>   designer's job, **however. No** matter how good a concept is it will
>   never be translated into a video game unless it is communicated
>   effectively.

Comment: I would place a comma after "no matter how good a concept is", too.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I think your question has not been well-received because it provides no background— why would it be *wrong* to put a period after *however*? I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal usage and is perfectly acceptable. Although the context is missing from the statement in the question, but my guess is that the author must have talked at a good length about the "conceptualization of a game" immediately prior to this sentence.

The author now wants to introduce a new and , to them, a more powerful concept with a bit of dramatic emphasis.

Lo and behold; it's effective communication!!